# Error: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded

Tags: node.js, windows, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to run [`oracledb`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#examplequerycb) in Node.js.

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
```

However, the oracle is failing to initialize the client libraries. The full error is:

> **Error**: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found". See
>   https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

Now I check their "help" article, but it just says to download some zip file with client libraries. So I did that, I extracted the archive and put it's path on the system path. These are the contents:

[image]

And here you can see that the path is indeed on system path:

[image]

The Node.js I'm running **is 64bit**.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of Oracle Client?

Comment: Please don't paste images. Copy/paste the information as text.

Comment: Perhaps you have to include also the `bin` path or your oracle folder.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yesm I downloaded the 64bit zip. I intentionally pasted screenshot of the path - it serves to show that the string is indeed in the path. If I just copied the relevant bit, it wouldn't be clear if I managed to change the PATH correctly.

Comment: Come on, you are a developer. If you write "folder xy is in my %PATH%" then the people here will believe it. Anyway, did you install the OLE DB provider? It is not part of the default InstantClient. According to your files it seems to be missing.

Comment: Have you gone through the Windows installation instructions for node-oracledb? https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instwin Note section 3.6.6.

Comment: I know this is late but may be someone may benefit from this answer. 
You need to install oracle client.Also set its path globally.
Alternatively you can download oracle client and unzip this folder in your `node_module/oraclbs/build/release/` folder.(not a preferred way but worked for me)